# remove duplicates from laravel array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, filter

```
foreach ($this->data as $row) {
$year = $row[$dataPositions['year']];
$name = $row[$dataPositions['name']];


$foundgames = &$this->foundgames;

    $game = $games->first(function($game, $key) use ($year, $name) {
    if ( $year === $game->year && $game->name === $name ) {
    return true;
    }
});
if ($game) {
    $game->number = $number;
    $game->catalog_name = $name;

    $this->foundgames[] = $game;

    $games = $games->filter(function($gam) use ($game) {
        return $game->id !== $gam->id;
    });
}
```

}

At this moment I gwr first game correctly and others will go to false, but how I can get all to false if some duplicate matched?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. Can you please explain your desired result a bit more?

Comment: $this->data  have data massive, where can be duplicates.
$games -> games current database
if something have duplicate, need remove it from 
$game = $games->first(function($game, $key) use ($year, $name) {

Comment: So you want to remove the duplicate objects in your collection, or?

Comment: Correct, lave unique only by year and name value

Comment: Check out Laravels [Collection method called 'unique'](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections#method-unique)

Comment: Thanks, but i checked if, it leave only one, but not remove all duplicates.
(exapmle: 1,2.2,2,3, it leave 1,2,3, I need 1,3)

Comment: actually first works as same thing...

Comment: Well.. If it return 1,2,3 then it works as intended.... It removes duplicates

Comment: Ok, fixing - i need remove ALL duplicate and original matching,  with what it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`groupBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby) method on a collection to group your `games` by their `id` and then use the [`reject`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-reject) method to remove any that have a `count` not equal to `1`.

I don't know the exact structure of your `game` collection/objects, however, the following provides the basic idea.

```
$collection = collect([
    ['id' => 1],
    ['id' => 2],
    ['id' => 2],
    ['id' => 3],
]);

$uniques = $collection->groupBy('id')->reject(function ($item) {
    return $item->count() !== 1;
});

dump($uniques); // outputs 1 & 3
```

Comment: Thanks, but  i need filter 2 values game  name and year, by 
games->groupBy(['name', 'year'])->reject(function ($item) {
 i get zero result,

Comment: @user7943875 Can you update your question to include an example of the data structure for your collection. That will help to provide an accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $collection = [
  ['id' => 1],
  ['id' => 2],
  ['id' => 2],
  ['id' => 3]];   
 $duplicates = collect($collection)->duplicates('id'); 
 if ($duplicates->isNotEmpty()) { 
    dd(" We Have Found Duplicate");
 }else{
   dd("No Duplicate Here");
 }
```

**This enough for find duplicate data from array**